# Does a vector array resize after erasing one/more elements?

Tags: c++, function, vector, size, erase

Does `vector.erase` resize the vector object so that I can measure the reduced size with `vector.size()`?

for example;

```
vector<int> v(5);
v = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

and I want to delete 4 by;

```
v.erase(v.begin()+4);
```

Does my vector object `v` have a size of 4 now. In other words is `v.size() == 4` after this operation?

Comment: Just try it or read the docs.

Comment: Btw., don't confuse size and capacity.

Comment: Whethet the .size() decreases or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, size **is decreased** as you erase elements.

---

Don't be afraid to test yourself though, by writing a minimal example, like this :) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(5);
    v = {1,2,3,4,5};
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    v.erase(v.begin()+4);
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

you would get:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x main.cpp 
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ ./a.out 
5
4
```

And we would expect that right? I mean the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) says:

> **Return size**
>
> Returns the number of elements in the vector.
>
> This is the number of actual objects held in the vector, which is not
>   necessarily equal to its storage capacity.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering whether that particular cell would be vacant or the consecutive elements would be shifted leftwards!

Comment: You are welcome @Kishaan92, make sure you *accept* the answer then! :) By the way, you should get used to writing minimal examples to test, when you are in doubt! :)

Comment: Yeah sure! I'll test it before posting it here next time. I'm a newbie to coding btw :)

Comment: I can sense that @Kishaan92, that's why I answered the question, otherwise I would have voted to close it. You see, I was pretty much like you at the start, but Stack Overflow (and some others) tought me how to overcome this fear! And now it's my turn... :)

Comment: Yeah, now I understand how to use Stack Overflow properly (i.e without getting any down votes ;) ) Hopefully I'll overcome my fear soon! :)